# Execute normal actions in vim from command mode

Tags: vim

We can type `:6d` in vim to immediately go to and delete line 6.

Is there a way to extend these commands to do normal operations? As an example, I’d like to do `:6V` to go to line 6 and select it, or do maybe something more complex, like `:6V12dd` which would select and delete lines from 6 to 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify ranges to commands from the command line in the form below

```
start,end
```

So if you wanted to delete lines 6 through 12 you could use

```
:6,12d
```

If you want to use normal mode commands from the command line take a look at the command [`normal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3anormal)